# How do I get rid of the declare/define error?

Tags: c++

I'm still trying to get to grips with C++ and I understand the idea and use of header files, but every time I try and implement one I get the same error every time

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Maths::addnumber(int, int)", referenced from:
  _main in main-3adee4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

I'm just trying to make it work at the minute with just a very basic add method just to actually make a header file work really but no matter what I've read so far I can't seem to fix it. Any help would be amazing thanks!

This is my tester.cpp

```
#include "tester.hpp"
using namespace std;

int Maths::addnumber(int x, int y)
{
    int ans = x + y;
    return ans;
}
```

This is my tester.hpp

```
#ifndef tester_hpp
#define tester_hpp

#include <stdio.h>


class Maths
{
public:
    int addnumber(int x, int y);

};


#endif /* tester_hpp */
```

This is my main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tester.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Maths test;
    test.addnumber(10,20);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling? It seems that you didn't link all your files together.

Comment: You're not linking your code correctly. You need to link both main.o and tester.o, but it's obvious that you're only linking main.o

Comment: clang++ main.cpp tester.cpp

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! Managed to sort it out :)